# jQuery: submit a form when the checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a form, and I want automatically to update it when I click on a checkbox.
This is my current code:

```
$('.option img').click(function() {
     $("#views-exposed-form-Portfolio-page-1").submit();
});
```

However, the selected checkbox is not stored before the form is submitted, and so the selection has not effect.

thanks

Comment: So you are building a submit button that looks like a checkbox? How confusing. (Tip: Don't do that. Use a submit button.)

Comment: @David Dorward - I'd give that many more upvotes if I could.

Comment: I have to agree with David.  This violates the Rule of Least Surprise: http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch11s01.html

Comment: hi! Hi forgot to mention that the submit button is not visible, so I want to update my page when a checkbox is checked.

Comment: Submitting the form when the checkbox is changed is not the solution; making the submit button visible is the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#myCheckBox").change(
    function(){
        $("#views-exposed-form-Portfolio-page-1").submit();   
    }
);
```

You can obviously check and see if the checkbox is checked before submitting the form, but this way is easier than submitting based on the click event (which fires before the change event, it seems).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that as the final thing then surely you can just store the reverse of what was already stored for it?

If it is always set to off, then you can always store 1 or if it could already have been stored then find that value and return the inverse of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".checkbox-class:checked")) {

$("#views-exposed-form-Portfolio-page-1").submit();   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the change event instead of the click event, or just select it manually.